# Is there a simpler/cleaner way to write this?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am using this code to sync with google storage. It works just want to know if there is a simpler and cleaner way to write this.

```
chrome.storage.sync.get(['titleCustom', 'textCustom', 'highCustom', 'quoteCustom', 'bgCustom'], (result) => {
    if(result.titleCustom !== undefined){
      document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--blue', result.titleCustom);
    }
    if(result.textCustom !== undefined){
      document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--light-text', result.textCustom);
    }
    if(result.highCustom !== undefined){
      document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--green', result.highCustom);
    }
    if(result.quoteCustom !== undefined){
      document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--dark-text', result.quoteCustom);
    }
    if(result.bgCustom !== undefined){
      document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--light-bg', result.bgCustom);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could create a object mapping the key in `result` (e.g. `titleCustom`) to the respective color (e.g. `--blue`), then iterate through the object and so something like this:

```
  // key:color are the variables of our outer for-each loop
  if(result[key] !== undefined) {
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty(color, result[key]);
  }
```

This has the additional effect that you can use `Object.keys(mapObject)` as parameter in `chrome.storage.sync.get` instead of the hard-coded array.

Answer (score 1):

Declare an object of key/values for the storage items where the key is the storage item and the value is the corresponding property you'd like to set for that key element.

```
let props = {
  "titleCustom": "--blue",
  "textCustom": "--light-text",
  "highCustom" :"--green",
  "quoteCustom": "--dark-text",
  "bgCustom": "--light-bg"
  }
];

let keys = Object.keys(props);

chrome.storage.sync.get(keys, (result) => {
  keys.forEach((element) => {
    if (element in result) {
      document.documentElement.style.setProperty(props[element], result[element]);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: `keys.map` - you are not doing a mapping operation here, so this is a misuse the `.map` method. You should be using `.forEach` instead or just a loop.